# Server Code for Shiny-Server for a Specific App is not showing any of the Dataframes

Tags: shiny-server

[image]So the ui.R file is working perfectly. However, the server.R is what I suspect may be causing the issue here. The intended behavior is that I have data frames display above the embedded HTML charts on each one of my pages. However, the data frames are not generated. The intended goal is to use the google sheets package, read a google sheet, and then morph it into a data frame exposed on R Shiny.

I have tried placing the data frame function and definition above and below within the ui.R and the server.R. However, I am not getting any return on any of the output.

This is for a Shiny-Server hosted on Ubuntu 16.04 Server.

```
#
# This is the server logic of a Shiny web application. You can run the
# application by clicking 'Run App' above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(googlesheets)
library(googleCharts)
library(googleAuthR)
library(stats)
library(searchConsoleR)
library(googleAnalyticsR)
library(httr)
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(mosaic)
library(DT)
library(httpuv)
library(htmltools)

# Google Sheets for Synced Keys with Data Master
# ===============================================
handover <- gs_key("1Wu8gJ#$%%#$%%#@#$@@$#%@@#$%@#%-VVHcB8c")
for_gs_sheet <- gs_read(handover)
str(for_gs_sheet)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  google_app <- oauth_app(
    "google",
    key = "3901########################m",
    secret = "b#########################z"
  )
  #oauth2.0_token(google_app)
    ## ---------- Google Authentication ---------- ##
    gs_auth(token = NULL ,new_user = FALSE,
            key = getOption("################.com"),
            secret = getOption("##############Ka5mz"),
            cache = getOption("googlesheets.httr_oauth_cache"), verbose = TRUE)

        for_gs_sheet <- gs_read(handover)
        str(for_gs_sheet)

    output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
        df <- gs_read(handover)
    })
})
```

[image]
The actual results should show output as related to the DT package. However, the data table is not being processed and/or is not made visible when called in the server output.

Comment: Also, the data for histdata is not showing, so I don't know if this has something to do with it as well.

Comment: It seems that I am having an Issue with google authentication here. Problem seems to stem from the fact that my application is asking me to redirect to a URL to approve the scopes for OAuth2.0 flow. Perhaps someone might have some insights I will provide the last output from tail of my shiny-server log.

Comment: I get a 400 request when I go to the redirect for the URL.

Comment: Waiting for authentication in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Please point your browser to the following url:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fspreadsheets.google.com%2Ffeeds%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A1410%2F&response_type=code&state=lSdkvL67X0

Comment: The other issue is when it finally does try to authenticate it loads but the screen is greyed out. I will share a picture of this. I did manage to partially fix the authentication in regards to OAuth flow by changing the hidden file permission for .httr_auth file to or 644.

Comment: What's interesting it that I am getting the following error. I wonder if there is something that is having issues with authentication within the app.

Comment: Error: invalid_request</b></p><p id="errorDescription">Missing required parameter: client_id</p><p id="errorUri"><a target="_blank" href="http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html">Learn more</a></p><div id="request_info_header">Request Details<ul id="request_info_items"><li class="param_entry" id="param_entry_0">scope=https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive</li><li class="param_entry"

Comment: It seems like something is wrong with the client_id. Does anyone have any thoughts on this issue?

Comment: Here is another issue with it: I have finally figured out that this issue is related to oauth. However, I getting a 400 response in the following manner. Seen the next comment.

Comment: 400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:1410/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/390198683818-i5fmprq9h09vcn6niu7v91bku2dvk1v5.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=390198683818

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stems from a service token issue. 
The best way is to just create a service token and session that maintains an open connection and refreshes the token.

I fixed this issue by backing the token directly into the app via JSON and having the app call the JSON file within the directory the shiny app was stored in under the /srv/ directory. You can download a copy of the service account information and store it in the working directory of the app:

```
root@miradashboard1:/srv/shiny-server/Apps/CSM# ls
miradashboard-f89f243d0221.json  server.R  ui.R
```

Then make sure you call the service token within the server.R and ui.R.

```
service_token <- gar_auth_service(json_file="/srv/shiny-server/Apps/CSM/miradashboard-f89f243d0221.json")
```